# Expo: WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync and related calls skip user input even when browser session expired

Tags: react-native, oauth, salesforce, expo

This is a summary of an issue [I filed directly with expo](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7763) (it ws closed but I have asked for it to be reopened):

> This issue happens whether using `AuthSession.startAsync`,
>   `AppAuth.authAsync` or `WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync` on iOS in
>   local development and published release (expo managed). Haven't tried
>   on standalone build yet.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. user presses 'sign in' button, (app calls one of the above methods to kick start authentication session with a Salesforce oauth provider)
2. user enters credentials successfully
3. app goes through oauth redirects and returns user to our app and we get our access token.
   user presses 'sign out' button (app calls revoke endpoint for token, then calls server endpoint to delete any browser cookie sessions for given account reference)
4. app navigates to sign in screen
5. user presses 'sign in' again (app calls the same method from above to start the authentication session with Salesforce oauth provider again)
6. instead of opening the sign in page, the app redirects itself back with an access token as if the user had successfully entered their credentials, even though any cookies/session data the browser stores should be invalid and necessitate a sign in.

**Expected Behaviour**

steps 1 - 5 are all as expected. Step six should be

6. app redirects to Salesforce oauth provider sign in page, in unauthenticated state (ie no cookie or session data that was previously stored is still valid)
7. user is required to re-enter their credentials
8. oauth flow takes over and redirects the user into the app if the credentials were correct.

**Actual Behavior**

as per initial steps where the user is not even asked to enter their credentials (step 6):

6. instead of opening the sign in page, the app redirects itself back with an access token as if the user had successfully entered their credentials, even though any cookies/session data the browser stores should be invalid and necessitate a sign in.

**Reproducible Demo**

The code is in a private repo so I can't share details of it, but it's a very standard oauth flow, and seeing it's happening in all three of the method calls from the top suggests to me that it may be due to something in the `WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync` implementation. I have seen on the [apple developer docs that SFAuthenticationSession has been deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession) in favour of [ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession). My understanding is that this (SFAuthenticationSession) is the browser used by expo's WebBrowser and the wrappers mentioned above (AppAuth and AuthSession) for the oauth interactions. I also see that it mentions it's for a one-time login, which perhaps explains why it would hold onto any session data and jump to the conclusion of re-authenticating without directly seeking credentials from the user, but it seems unhelpful to store a cookie without validating it, which is what appears to be the end result.

**Notes**

Essentially this is making it impossible for a user to sign out of our app, because the system browser, that we don't have control over, is keeping track of their authentication despite the session value no longer being valid against the server.

I've seen other people looking to find ways to clear cookies from the system browser, which may be what this issue relates to, though it doesn't appear to be possible to access the auth session's browser cookies in any way. [This comment on a GitHub issue is exactly what I'm experiencing](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6756#issuecomment-584520743) and need to find a solution to.

I would like users to be able to sign out, and then when they sign back in again they should have to enter their credentials again. Does anyone have any thoughts as to how this might be possible?

Comment: I was having the same issue but with the `useAuthRequest` hook. I found that it took a AuthRequestConfig option called `prompt` and when I set that to `Prompt.Login` I was able to get the login screen again.

Comment: I tried that too, as well as the `select_account` option. All this did was open up the Salesforce application in a signed-in state, which was even worse than immediately redirecting back into our react native app.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, it's now possible to pass in the following config to WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync to essentially treat it as incognito and ensure it doesn't retain any cookies.  The effect is that the user will have to re-authenticate each time (even if there session is still active).  I'm not aware of a similar approach for Android, however.

### Code

```
const browserOptions = {
   preferEphemeralSession: true
}

result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(authUrl, redirect, browserOptions)
```